# UseEffect hook not running

Tags: reactjs, json, react-hooks

I'm trying to run the useEffect hook to fetch the data from a json file. However, the useEffect does not run and thus the screen shows up blank. This is the part of the code where I have tried to fetch the data and update the state.

```
const RestaurantLayout = ({ children: Component, ...props }) => {
    const [restaurant, setRestaurant] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("useEffect called");
        fetch('/restaurantData.json')
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response)
            return response.json();})
        .then((resData) => {
            setRestaurant(resData);
        })
        .catch(error => console.error(error));
    }, [])
```

Here the json file is in the public folder.

However when I was finding out ways to solve this, I copied the json data from the json file and put it in the useState manually, then the useEffect did run. This is the code:

```
const RestaurantLayout = ({ children: Component, ...props }) => {
    const [restaurant, setRestaurant] = useState([
        {
            _id: "1",
            isPro: true,
            isOff: false,
            name: "Nathu's Sweets",
            address: "Ashok Vihar, New Delhi",
            restaurantRating: "3.7",
            cuisine: [
                "North Indian",
                "Sweets",
                "South Indian",
                "Chinese",
                "Street Food",
                "Fast Food",
                "Desserts"
            ],
        costForOne: "350",
        images: [
                {
                    "location":
                        "/tiffin3.jpg"
                },
                {
                    "location":
                        "/foodimg1.jpg"
                },
                {
                    "location":
                        "/foodimg2.jpg"
                },
                
                {
                    "location":
                        "/foodimg3.jpg"
                }
            ]
        },
])

useEffect(() => {
        console.log("useEffect called");
        fetch('/restaurantData.json')
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response)
            return response.json();})
        .then((resData) => {
            setRestaurant(resData);
        })
        .catch(error => console.error(error));
    }, [])
```

I cannot figure out why. Please help me out.

Comment: Can you check whether this component is rendered or not? if it is rendered then only the useEffect() hook will be called.

Comment: Yes the component is rendered

Comment: Have you got any errors in the useEffect's catch block, If you got, share that error as well

Comment: In the fetch API, instead of /restaurantData.json, use ./restaurantData.json, I think the file path is wrong

Comment: I tried to use ./restaurantData.json as well. Didn't work

Comment: The useEffect does not run when the state is initially empty. And since the state is empty, when the component renders this error is shown in the console:  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'images')

Comment: Can you share component with html source code?

Answer (score 0):

you can really only fetch an api endpoint. Your path `/restaurantData.json` doesn't resolve to such an endpoint.

You would have to **create an api** OR **hard code your json data** as you have done it in your second code example.

The preferred way would be to create an api. You could use something like **[express.js](https://expressjs.com)** (only API) or an React Framework like **[next.js](https://nextjs.org)** which has also support for creating Restful APIs.

Here is an example of an next.js api endpoint where json data is getting sent:
https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction

Comment: I have used the same path /restaurantData.json in another file and there it works fine.

Comment: @emilianscheel, We can also read the local system JSON file by using javascript fetch API